# Re-aligning Javascript/Canvas drawing?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I have a semi-complex canvas drawing someone gave me. It draws an image vertically (i.e., top-down).  Let's assume its a stick figure with facial features.

This is done in Javascript and Canvas. i.e.: `ctx.beginPath()`, `ctx.moveTo(x,y)`, `ctx.lineTo(1,1)`, etc.

I want the stick figure to move towards some point (x,y) and to face that direction while moving toward it. For example, if the x,y is near the bottom right, I want the stick figure to be oriented in a way such that its feet are facing towards the bottom right while it is moving.

The main question is, how would I go about doing this (i.e changing the stickman), knowing that I have a "hardcoded" drawing (in this example, stickman) that has been given to me?

Comment: You may be able to render the received image on a separate canvas (doesn't need to be displayed) and use `ctx.canvas.toDataURL()` to convert it to an image.  You could then embed the resulting image in your canvas and apply transforms to it more easily.

Comment: Thanks, this is the approach I will use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render the received image on a separate canvas (doesn't need to be displayed) and use ctx.canvas.toDataURL() to convert it to an image. You could then embed the resulting image in your canvas and apply transforms to it more easily.

I mentioned this in a comment on the question but it sounded like fun, so I implemented a proof of concept.

```js
var canvasObject = function(ctx) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.arc(30,30,15,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle='red';
  ctx.fill();
  return ctx;
}

var myCtx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
var objCtx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
var renderedObjUrl = canvasObject(objCtx).canvas.toDataURL();
var renderedObj = document.createElement('img');
renderedObj.setAttribute('src', renderedObjUrl);

myCtx.drawImage(renderedObj, 30, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: you absolutely don't need and most of the time should not convert the canvas to a dataURL, `ctx.drawImage` accepts `<canvas>` as imageSource.

Comment: I did not realize that it take a canvas element directly.  That's good to know.

Comment: Also, if you do use an `<img>` tag, you shall always attach the drawing in its `onload` event handler, your snippet doesn't work in FF for this reason. This can be avoided by drawing directly the canvas.